# Modifying JavaDb Relationships visually (like in access) In Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, javadb

Does the JavaDb editor in Netbeans have something that would allow me to modify relationships visually like in MS-Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, visually modifying relationships is not possible. You can do it though using proper commands.